# How to update a nested attribute containing a certain value to another value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to update a nested attribute containing a certain value to another value in elasticsearch (i.e. for index `users` how to update all documents which have a certain value say `status='Active' to status='Upgrade'`)